# overwrite authenticate_user! in devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm overwriting my authenticate method in my application controller

```
def authenticate_worker!
  if user_signed_in? && current_user.worker?
    authenticate_user!
  else
    super
  end
end
```

I keep getting

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:51:in `authenticate_worker!'
```

Any idea what i'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it. It was passing `{:force=>true}`
Not sure what that argument does though...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and fixed it doing this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protected
  def authenticate_user!(opts={}) 
    opts[:scope] = :user
    warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
    flash[:alert] = "I always have to monkeypatch devise... because I'm lazy to use the sorcery gem."
  end
end
```

So, wrapping. up, copy and paste the code above and substitute flash[:alert] with what you want to do after you are sure the user is authenticated.

The `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error happens because of the `opts` optional parameter.

Comment: you are correct, the opts is {:force=>true} in most cases. Sorry my answer was not clear.

Comment: @thiagofm additional :+1: for the flash alert message :D

Comment: You may call `super(opts) ` so you don't rewrite Devise's code. See `Devise::Controllers::Helpers#define_helpers`.